# ¿Cómo actualizar otra web al insertar mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos `mysql`. Necesito que cuando un valor especifico se cambie en una tabla, se actualice la pagina principal. No estoy viendo la página. Es correr algún comando para que se ejecute un `refresh`, pero solamente cuando exista un cambio en la Base de datos `mysql`.

Ejemplo: tengo una página abierta e inserto manualmente algo en `mysql`. ¿Cómo hago para que aparezca en la pagina el cambio sin actualizar con f5?

Comment: Cuentanos un poco que más estás usando en "página" ¿`php`,`jsp`? ¿algún otro? Así sería un poco más fácil orientarte a una solución para tu problema, por el momento te recomiendo que leas un poco sobre `AJAX`

Comment: ok es php con mysql la pagina esta abierta y desde otra web estoy insertando datos en mysql, hay una tabla llamada orders, necesito que cuando la tabla orders, el campo status orders cambie de numero 1 a 2 a 3 o cualquier cambio, en otra pagina abierta se actualice sola, o ejecute un reload cada vez que el campo status orden cambie de numero

Comment: algo como que le pregunta a la tabla y campo mysql condicion si hay un cambio ejecuta un reload en la pagina index.php de lo contrario no hagas nada

Comment: pero la pagina index esta abierta y no se esta insertando el dato por la web , es decir no hay un sumit, ya que este dato insertado viene de otra pag

Comment: solo el index.php debe actualizarse apenas detecte el cambio en la tabla.

Comment: algo como esta web stackoverflow.com que cuando llega una respuesta nueva pararece un numero arriba de la bandeja de entrada y se carga el nuevo mensaje sin actulizar la pagina, esto es produscto de que alguien por otra web dio una respuesta actulizo la base de datos y aqui aparece la alerta de que tienes un mensaje nuevo y sin oprimir f5 para actualizar, no tengo idea de como empezar o si hay algo ya hecho

Comment: Yo creo que debe haber un cronjob o job que se consulta constantemente si hay cambios o no respecto (por ejemplo aqui) a una sesion de usuario o algo por estilo.

Comment: ok como hago esa pregunta en el cron ???

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu pregunta es muy amplia, deberías dar más información sobre cómo está montada tu página web, para que así podamos ayudarte mejor. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta, o mirar en el centro de ayuda cómo preguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que, cuando haya un cambio en ese valor, se refresque la página, puedes utilizar el siguiente código.

```
 var timeOutId = 0;
  var ajaxFn = function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/verificar_si_hay_cambios',//método php que devuelve si ha habido cambios o no verficando la base de datos
          success: function (response) {
              if (response == 'True') { //Hay cambios
                  clearTimeout(timeOutId);
                  location.reload();
                  console.log("La recargo");
              } else { //No hay cambios, pruebo dentro de 10 segundos de nuevo
                  timeOutId = setTimeout(ajaxFn, 10000);
                  console.log("pruebo dentro de 10 sg.");
              }
          }
      });
  }
  ajaxFn();
```